# How can I send the info in a form Portlet to another portlet?

Tags: javascript, netsuite, suitescript

I am trying to have a form portlet that takes in a field of info and either sends the info to another portlet or sends it back to itself to render the content in HTML. 
I know there are separate HTML and Form portlets but could it be possible to have some mix of the two or have them interact with each other. Essentially I want it to look like the below. Is this possible?

Portlet to enter info

```
function port1(portlet){
  portlet.addField('text', 'text', 'Text');
portlet.setSubmitButton('url to another portlet', 'Submit');
}
```

Portlet that receives info and outputs the HTML

```
function port2(request, response){
   var info = request.getBody();
   request.setHTML(info);
}
```

Comment: 1. are you talking about separate functions in the same resource or also about separate resources (i.e. JS files)?  2. Assuming you have addressed #1 and the functions are now in scope then you can call a function from another and pass appropriate arguments.   Please clarify the context.

Comment: Either one. It'd be ideal if I could have it all in one file. I tried doing it in one file like it is depicted above but no luck. I don't think you can pass request and response to a portlet. Am I wrong?